# Problema com conexão ao BD com codeigniter (mysqli)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

Galera, fiz um form de cadastro para newsletter. E ao carregar o database no `autoload['libraries']`, apresenta um erro

> Call to undefined function mysqli_init() in /home/softlove/public_html/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php on line 136

Alguém pode me ajudar?

View-Form:

```
 <form action="index.php/usuario/newsletter">
                     <div class="form-group">
                         <label for="nome">Nome</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="Nome">
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="seuemail@email.com">
                      </div>
                      <div align="center">

                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Cadastrar</button>
                      </div>
                    </form>
```

Model

```
<?php
class UsuarioDAO extends CI_Model {

    public function cadastrarDadosUsuario($nome, $email) {
       $this->load->library('database');
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO signups (signup_nome, signup_email_address) VALUES (?, ?)", array($nome, $email));

        // Inserir código de tratamento de erros...
    }
}
```

Controller

```html
<?php
class Usuario extends CI_Controller {


    public function newsletter() {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('nome', 'Nome do usuário', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'E-mail do usuário', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run()) { // Se os dados foram recebidos com sucesso
            $nome = $this->input->post('nome');
            $email = $this->input->post('email');

            /* Carrega a classe que trata da tabela do usuário no banco. 
               Este método pega como referência a pasta application/models.
               Se a classe a ser carregada estiver em algum subdoínio, este deve ser informado também. pe.: $this->load->model('dao/UsuarioDAO');
            */
            $this->load->model('UsuarioDAO');
            $this->UsuarioDAO->cadastrarDadosUsuario($nome, $email);

            // Busque inserir códigos de tratamentos de erros caso o banco gere algum erro.

        } else {
            // código de tratamento de erro...
        }
    }
}
```

database.php

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'host',
    'username' => 'user',
    'password' => 'senha',
    'database' => 'db',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('form_validation','database');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ja tive este problema, e no caso era o driver mysqli que não estava habilitado no meu php.

Veja se no seu php.ini o driver esta habilitado, e em caso de duvidas, utilize o link abaixo para consulta.

[Codeigniter: fatal error call to undefined function mysqli_init()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33612956/codeigniter-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysqli-init)

Comment: Era exatamente isso !!! Obrigado tkmattos!